# fetchSignInMethodsForEmail gives an empty email field on a TOAST

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have a pretty simple challenge here USING firebase Auth by email. I
first check if the email exists which is working well. but the program
gives me a toast of "Please enter email..." Check me code
below.

Should proceed next if the email does not exist. when email does not
exist. my  `(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))`  toast to me to enter the
email.

```
public class RegistreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText e4;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    String email;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registre);
        e4 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.temail);
        auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }
    public  void  goToPasswordActivity(View v){    
        auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(e4.getText().toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SignInMethodQueryResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){

                        boolean check =!task.getResult().getSignInMethods().isEmpty();
                        if (!check){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistreActivity.this,PasswordActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("email",e4.getText().toString());
                            startActivity(intent);    
                        }
                        else {    
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"email alredy exst",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter email...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }    
                    }    
                }
            });    
        }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never seem to be giving `email` a value anywhere, which explains why `if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))` executes the block of code that shows the toast you don't want.

I suspect that you want `email` to be the value the user entered into `e4.getText().toString()`. If that's the case, I'd recommend doing that before the call to `auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`, and also to check whether the user entered a value there, instead of after the call to Firebase.

So something like:

```
String email = e4.getText().toString();
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter email...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else {    
    auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SignInMethodQueryResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    boolean check =!task.getResult().getSignInMethods().isEmpty();
                    if (!check){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegistreActivity.this,PasswordActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("email", email);
                        startActivity(intent);    
                    }
                    else {    
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"email already exst",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }    
            }
        });    
    }  
}
```